# How can I write script to check CSV file for blank cells from existing csv?

Tags: python, linux, bash

How can I script loop an existing csv and output to a new file in the output similar below to blankfruits.csv still keeping the header title but capturing the null cells there after and stop once all found.

```
# fruitbowl.csv

fruit bowl A
- - - - -
apples
bananas
pears
coconuts

fruit bowl B
- - - - -
apples
bananas
pears
coconuts


fruit bowl C
- - - - -


fruit bowl D
- - - - -
apples
bananas
pears
coconuts

fruit bowl E
- - - - -


fruit bowl F
- - - - -
```

The idea will be for the bash script or maybe python to read the existing CSV and output to new file with

```
# blankfruits.csv

fruit bowl C
- - - - -


fruit bowl E
- - - - -


fruit bowl F
- - - - -
```

Comment: Please use the coding environment and [edit] your post and show how exactly your data looks. Also add a [mre] of what you tried to do. You could simply read a file line by line, see if a line starts with "fruit bow" - then create a new list and store the current lines text - then add all following lines (that are not empty, that do not start with "fruit bowl") to this list. When encountering a new line of "fruit bowl" check if your list is empty (or only contains a line with ----- in) and if so write it to a new file (stored current line text & empty list).

Comment: It seems the format is not CSV (**comma** separated values) but rather NSV (**newline** separated values).

Comment: If you just need it done, you can use this awk: `awk -v RS= 'NF==8' file` but if you need to learn something out of it, then the answer is probably going to be longer, probably the quoestion too.

Answer (score 1):

here is a quick one-liner: (based on your example)

```
$ awk -v RS="" '{a=gsub(ORS,ORS);if(a==1)print $0 ORS}' YourInput
fruit bowl C
- - - - -

fruit bowl E
- - - - -

fruit bowl F
- - - - -
```

Comment: The format typed into this question was just to get an idea of the results I am after. So essentially what I want the script to do is read existing CSV file in path with the contents in that format and then check and spit out a new file name with results @Kent provided in response

Comment: @Nza you can redirect the output to a file.

Comment: so awk -v RS="" '{a=gsub(ORS,ORS);if(a==1)print $0 ORS}' fruitbowl.csv is not giving me desired result i am after - Please kindly advise with snippet to use

Comment: `RS=""` won't work if your `fruitbowl.csv` has Windows line endings, ie. `\r\n` instead of just `\n`. You did tag [tag:linux] so this might not be the case but could try to strip `\r`s off with: `awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")}1' fruitbowl.csv | awk -v RS="" '{a=gsub(ORS,ORS);if(a==1)print $0 ORS}'` or describe the output you got more thoroughly than _not giving me desired result i am after_.

Comment: @Nza I have tested it with your data, using both `\r\n` and `\n` line endings.

Comment: @Nza We don't have fruitbowl.csv, if you want us to have it, you need to provide it.

Comment: I did not see any upload icon here :(